# Tinymce 4.0.5 math plugin

Tags: tinymce

I use tinymce editor version 4.0.5.i want to use Math/Graph Plugins in updated tinymce when I add math plugin in new version of tinymce its not working and give the error plugin.min.js not found .How can i convert plugins file into plugin.min.js or any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

to convert the plugin to version 4, have a look at : 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This answer could be improved if you could add more than just a link to another page.  The trouble with link-only answers is that they tend to become invalid over time.  Please click "edit" if you can think of a way to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed few plugins for **TinyMCE 4** to work with Math Font/symbols, Math Graphs and Charts.

Please take a look at my projects:

- Math Font/Symbols: https://github.com/Axel186/mathsymbols-tinymce-plugin
- Math Graphs: https://github.com/Axel186/graphs-tinymce-plugin
- Math Charts: https://github.com/Axel186/charts-tinymce-plugin

Feel free to ask me questions.